# login_user fails to get user id

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

My app fails whenever I call `login_user` with the error `NotImplementedError: No 'id' attribute - override 'get_id'`.  My user has an id attribute.  Why does this fail?

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()

    if user is not None and user.verify_password(form.password.data):
        print(user.user_id)
        login_user(user, False)
        return jsonify({'response': user.user_id})
```

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`login_user` calls `get_id` on the user instance.  `UserMixin` provides a `get_id` method that returns the `id` attribute or raises an exception.  You did not define an `id` attribute, you named it (redundantly) `user_id`.  Name your attribute `id` (preferably), or override `get_id` to return `user_id`.

Answer (score 28):

You just need to add a  `get_id()` function in order to override the default properties of `get_id()` under the User class in the models.py file where your database schema is defined.

```
class User(#...):
    # ...
    def get_id(self):
           return (self.user_id)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you make `return User.get_id(id)` to work. In my case User model is defined as:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

but `load_user` would still get error:
`AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'get'`

Quite a few tutorials online including [RealPython](https://realpython.com/using-flask-login-for-user-management-with-flask/) implementation deviates from documentation, but worked for me:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```